# How to count occurrence of list of words in the first n lines of multiple files?

Tags: shell, terminal, grep, macos-sierra, head

i currently have a list of terms - words.txt,with each term on one line, and I want to count how many total occurrences for all those terms exists in the first 500 lines of multiple csv files in the same directory.

I currently have something like this:

```
grep -Ff words.txt /some/directory |wc -l
```

How exactly can I get the program to display for each file the count number for just those first 500 lines of each file? Do i have to create new files with the 500 lines? How can i do that for a large number of original files? I'm very new to coding and working on a dataset for research, so any help is much appreciated!

Edit: I want it to display something like this but for each file:

```
grep -Ff words.txt list1.csv |wc -l
/Users/USER/Desktop/FILE/list1.csv:28
```

Comment: it would be better if have shown a complete cycle on a single input file, `words.txt` fragment and expected result for those

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

> head /some/directory/* -n 100 | grep -Ff words.txt | wc -l
>
> `Sample Result: 38`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get the following errors once running that line of code with the directory path specified: 
    head: -n: No such file or directory
     head: 5: No such file or directory
          11

Comment: Can you run this command in your terminal then show me the result?   lsb_release -a

Comment: Please give me Operating System. Is it linux, mac, solaris? and what is the version?

Comment: it is macOS High Sierra, version 10.13.3

Comment: Do you have a binary file in /usr/bin named head? Probably you have a binary in your systeam called "head".

Comment: I do. Should I delete it?